# Как правильно передать данные из формы на другую страницу html?

Tags: php, html, input

Есть похожий вопрос, но я не получил желаемого результата после действий, рекомендованных там. У меня есть index.html и welcome_page.php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  <title>HTML forms</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="container">
      <form id="myform" action="welcome_page.php" method="post">
        <h3 class="form_title pads">Введите свои данные</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <input class="inputs" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First name" required />
          <input class="inputs" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Surname" required />
          <input class="inputs" type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age" required />
        </div>
          <input class="inputs" placeholder="Email" type="email" id="email" name="email" />


        <input class="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick='location.href="action.html"' required />
      </form>


      <p class="bottomText pads">
        Click "Submit" button to go to the Welcome page.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/welcome_page.css" />
    <title>Welcowe!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="container">
      <h2>Здравствуйте, <?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?><?php echo $_POST['lname']; ?>! 
Сегодня Вам исполняется <?php echo $_POST['age']; ?> лет. 
В честь этого наш коллектив поздравляет Вас с днем рождения, а также желает успехов в лчиной жизни и карьере. 
На ваш email <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?> выслана поздравительная открытка.</h2>
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Когда я нажимаю "Submit" то вместо сраницы с текстом открывается просто php код. Как исправить?

Comment: если у вас сервер не настроен показывать html как php, переименуйте файл в action.php и соотвественно измените ссылку

Comment: После этого ничего не изменилось. Ведь это просто название. Все еще открывается код php файла вмесо запарщенного текста из формы

Comment: вы сделали эти два файла и просто открываете их в браузере? для обработки php файлов нужен сервер